# DNA replication program generating wrong output

Tags: c, string

What is the problem with that code, I just want to replace the DNA's bases.:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getDna(){
    int i,t;
    printf("How many protein does the DNA have?");
    scanf("%d",&t);
    char dnaPtn[t],rDnaPtn[t];
    printf("Enter the DNA: ");
    scanf("%s",&dnaPtn);
    for(i=0;i<t;i++){
        switch(dnaPtn[i]){
            case 'a':
                rDnaPtn[i] = "t";
                break;
            case 'c':
                rDnaPtn[i] = "g";
                break;
            case 'g':
                rDnaPtn[i] = "c";
                break;
            case 't':
                rDnaPtn[i] = "a";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    printf("%s",rDnaPtn);
}

int main(){
    getDna();
    return 0;
}
```

The output of `agcta` is:

How many protein does the DNA have: 5

```
Enter the DNA: agcta
^b'd^!!@
```

What is wrong?

Comment: When compiling, always enable the compiler warnings.  (for gcc, at a minimum, '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')   Then fix the warnings.

Comment: regarding this line:  'scanf("%s",&dnaPtn);'  1) dnaPtn is an array.  in C, an array name degrades to the address of the array, so using the '&' is incorrect.  2) when inputting a string, using "%s", always include a max length modifier so the user cannot overrun the input buffer

Answer (score 4):

In your code,

```
 rDnaPtn[i] = "t";
```

should be

```
rDnaPtn[i] = 't';
```

as the `""` denotes a *string* but what you want is of type `char`.

After that,

- don't forget to null-terminate your destination array.
- `scanf("%s",&dnaPtn);` can be re-written as `scanf("%s",dnaPtn);`
- Don't loop over the *entire* array. make use of `strlen()`.

---

**Enable compiler warnings.**

Comment: I am emphatically agreeing with the important message you provided

Comment: what is null-terminate? :(

Comment: @Aegus add `int len = strlen(dnaPtn). for (i = 0; i < len; i++) { ..//do something}  rDnaPtn[i] = '\0';`